# adding new features to pyspark dataframe takes 8 hours and doesnt finish

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

The following function adds some features to a dataframe which is about 6k rows only.
However after 8 hours running it didnt finish, what am I doing wrong?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def add_rain_features(df, lag_hours=7):
    """
    Preprocesses the input PySpark DataFrame for training a machine learning model to predict buffer size value.

    Args:
    df (pyspark.sql.DataFrame): Input PySpark DataFrame with the following columns:
        - Location
        - Timestamp
        - Value (sludge in cubic meters)
        - Min of the sludge buffer
        - Max of the sludge buffer
        - Rain 1h (the amount of rain in mm at that timestamp)
        - Value_diff (the amount the sludge has increased or decreased since the previous hour in cubic meters)
    lag_hours (int): Number of lag hours for rain features.

    Returns:
    pyspark.sql.DataFrame: Processed DataFrame with lag features and additional suggested features.
    """
    # Initialize a Spark session
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PrepareData").getOrCreate()

    # Sort the DataFrame by Timestamp
    window_spec = Window.partitionBy("kp").orderBy("timestamp_hour")

    df = df.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(window_spec))
    df = df.orderBy("row_num").drop("row_num")

    # Generate lag features for rain
    for lag in range(1, lag_hours + 1):
        lag_col_name = f'Rain_{lag}h_ago'
        df = df.withColumn(lag_col_name, F.lag(df["rain_1h"], lag).over(window_spec))

    # Suggested additional features
    # 1. Rolling statistics for rain
    df = df.withColumn("Rain_mean_2h", F.avg(df["rain_1h"]).over(Window.partitionBy("kp").orderBy("timestamp_hour").rowsBetween(-1, 0)))
    df = df.withColumn("Rain_mean_3h", F.avg(df["rain_1h"]).over(Window.partitionBy("kp").orderBy("timestamp_hour").rowsBetween(-2, 0)))
    df = df.withColumn("Rain_mean_4h", F.avg(df["rain_1h"]).over(Window.partitionBy("kp").orderBy("timestamp_hour").rowsBetween(-3, 0)))
    df = df.withColumn("Rain_mean_5h", F.avg(df["rain_1h"]).over(Window.partitionBy("kp").orderBy("timestamp_hour").rowsBetween(-4, 0)))
    df = df.withColumn("Rain_mean_6h", F.avg(df["rain_1h"]).over(Window.partitionBy("kp").orderBy("timestamp_hour").rowsBetween(-5, 0)))

    # Stop the Spark session when done
    spark.stop()

    return df
```

Comment: Have you tried adding print statements around the function to see where exactly it's getting stuck?

Comment: if I remove all lines below:  # 1. Rolling statistics for rain
    df = df.withColumn("Rain_mean_2h", F.a
Then its really fast

Comment: You mean `Rain_mean_2h` alone works fast but `Rain_mean_3h` to `Rain_mean_6h` are slow? or is it deleting all the lines after `# 1. Rolling statistics for rain` that makes it fast?

Comment: Could you try separating `Window.partitionBy("kp").orderBy("timestamp_hour").rowsBetween(-1, 0)`, `Window.partitionBy("kp").orderBy("timestamp_hour").rowsBetween(-2, 0)`, etc... outside the `over` method and see how many rows are returned each time? Or perhaps add sample values for df, instead of 6000 do it with 10 rows and see what the end result looks like

Comment: What happens if you put `spark.stop()` outside the function?

Comment: I dont undertstand @Daviid

Comment: Materialize the dataframe and simultaneously cache it with `df.cache().count()` 

`for lag in range(1, lag_hours + 1):
        lag_col_name = f'Rain_{lag}h_ago'
        df = df.withColumn(lag_col_name, F.lag(df["rain_1h"], lag).over(window_spec)) 
        df.cache().count()
`

Basically don't chain it too long. Keep materializing the dataframe inbetween your calls with `df.cache().count()`

This is the hard lesson I learnt in my job.